# What does Django-admin.py startproject do exactly?

Tags: python, django

I just started out using python and went straight to django. I have set up a first project and played around a bit. So far so good. Now I'm trying to get a deeper understanding of what is going on.

I can't find any info on what startproject actually does. I understand it creates the page-structure of a Django-project, but does it do anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
# running django-admin.py inside /opt
/opt$ django-admin.py startproject testproject
```

Created structure:

- /opt

  - testproject

    - `manage.py` (the script which you use instead of django-admin.py for this project)
    - testproject (the directory which keeps the codebase for your project)
    - `__init__.py` (this file let's Python know that this folder is a package)
    - `settings.py` (django settings file created from a template)
    - `urls.py` (Django URLs file in which you put all your URL structure)
    - `wsgi.py` (the WSGI script which you can use to serve your application later on)

That's pretty much it.

Comment: No I just wanted to make sure that I didn't misunderstand anything. I had a feeling that the project was somehow registered by django or something like that...

Comment: Ah no, it is completely local.